# How does the method assigned to onreadystatechange execute so fast?

Tags: javascript, ajax

In the example below, if I click the button, it changes the content instantly. I am wondering why there isn't some delay like if I was to reload the page. Because, from the code, it looks like loadDoc() doesn't run until I click the button. At which time, the code requests the information from the server and changes it. But it seems to happen instantaneously, with no delay. Does the function loadDoc run before I click, so that when I click it already has the responseText?

```
<div id="demo">
<h2>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe it's just a a very fast ajax call?  Have your determined that the request is actually hitting your server?

Comment: Ok, so normally I can expect a little delay? (No, I haven't, I am viewing an example on another site)

Comment: Yes. Assume any network-related functions will take an unknown amount of time to complete. Write your logic in a way that doesn't depend on the loading speed of ajax requests